# Which regression should be used with one dependent variable and time as independent variable?

Tags: regression, time-series, panel-data

I am measuring companies' sustainability score over time, to see if it increased or decreased after the introduction of a regulation (exogenous shock) I only have one dependent variable and time as independent variable. Which regression makes more sense?

Comment: How many time points are we talking here?

Comment: Time is defined in years in my data; so 9 years. (Period pre regulation inlcudes a 4year -period and post regulation a 5year-period) Thanks!

Comment: if you plot the sustainability scores as a function of time (ignoring the event at this stage), how does the relationship seem to be visually? Linear? Quadratic?

Comment: Please add this new information as an edit to the post, so more people can see it.- Few people reads comments, and we want the posts to be self-contained. Comments here can be deleted anytime